# Asymptotic expansion of the solution to $y^x=x^y$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, lambert-w

I was reading this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_x%CA%B8_%3D_y%CB%A3 on the solutions to $y^x=x^y$. It is stated that the non-trivial solution tends to $1$   as $$1+\frac{\log{x}}{x}+o\!\left (\frac{\log{x}}{x} \right)$$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$. I was wondering how to prove this, but I haven't found anything about it on the web.
Could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you indicate your background e.g. what do you know about asymptotic expansions. Near the bottom of the page it is said $y=\exp( W_{-1}(\ln (x^x)))$ which probably gives the expansion after say looking through the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov) (in particular https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13)

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is for another problem (cf. the title of the section "Similar graphs").

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks  for pointing out the error @Gary

Answer (score 1):

The non-trivial solution for $x>e$ is
$$
y = \exp \left( { - W_0 \left( {-\frac{{  \log x}}{x}} \right)} \right)
$$
where $W_0$ is the principal branch of the Lambert $W$-function. From the Maclaurin expansion of this function, we have
$$
\exp \left( { - W_0 (z)} \right) = \exp \left( { - z + z^2  -  \cdots } \right) = 1 - z + \frac{3}{2}z^2  +  \cdots,
$$
for $|z|<\frac{1}{e}$. Take $z=-\frac{{ \log x}}{x}$ and the result follows.